# What is this div collapse an example of?

Tags: css-float

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pastic/sc8bn4t3/10/) to illustrate my question.

I have a floated div with no height (`.card`). It contains a nested div (`.image`) with an image. The image makes the bounding box of `.card` expand to wrap the image.

However, when I nest a second div (`.text`) inside `.card` as a sibling to `.image` and use negative margin-top to position `.text` in top of the image, the image no longer manages to expand the bounding-box of `.card` to match the bottom of the image. The bottom-boundary of `.card` instead creeps up and follows the bottom boundary of `.text`.

Why does not the image succeed in expanding its grand-parent any longer when `.text` is present?

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55892413/jsfiddle/image.jpg" width="200px"></div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55892413/jsfiddle/image.jpg" width="200px"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>

img {
  display: block;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid black; //shows where the bounding-box of this div is 
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.text {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: -120px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Too confusing question. I'm wonder you will get more view.. Please clear your question little bit more. Thank you

Comment: if m not wrong you want this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/sc8bn4t3/11/

Comment: Please, see below. (I have lots of work and could not respond immediately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If m not wrong to get your point then you are missing position:absolute.

Remember you can fix position of inside element only when parent div is relative and inside element absolute.

**UPDATED**

This issue is occurring because you are trying to use .txt(child) inside .card(parent) with position relative but with wrong way. Remember whenever you are using position, parent should be relative and child will be absolute so child will move inside parent container without breaking the flow(in your case it is affecting the parent div and breaking the border) so to over come this issue use position:absolute on child and then you can use .txt class with ease.

Just change `position: relative;` `to position: absolute;` in .text class and you are done.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/sc8bn4t3/11/)

Comment: Hi. Yes and no. Absolute positioning is what I use on the site in question to get the desired effect (image overlayed on text). But I am not asking for a solution, I am trying to understand why the (fail) situation in the fiddle occurs, thus deepening my CSS. The effect that the border no longer goes around the image when the red box is added to the equation is not random, is it? But I cannot understand why that is so.

Comment: @pastic please read my solution for that issue too. I just did not post the answer but lines too. I said to put image inside element with position absolute and it will only work with relative parent or else it will behave like out of box and thats what happening.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand better.

Comment: My pleasure..still if you have any doubt..ping here :)